# Creating a treeview of google drive folders

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script, treeview

I want to create a JSON database of folders (only) from google drive for a tree view pane,
I have tried to extract the database using google sheets using this code

```js
var level=0;
getFnF()

function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder= folder || DriveApp.getFolderById(" ID HERE");
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    var forg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1,level + 1);
    forg.setValue(Utilities.formatString(subfolder.getName() + "      "+ subfolder.getId()));
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```

but i stuck on how transforming it to a database such this formate :

```js
export const treeMenu = [
  {
    key: "Folder id",
    label: "folder1",
    nodes: [
      {
        key: "Folder id",
        label: "sub-folder",
        nodes: [
          {
            key: "Folder id",
            label: "sub-sub-folder",
            nodes: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "Folder id",
    label: "folder",
  },
];
```

Comment: I think your asking how to use the level and that's kind of application specific so it's kind of up to you.  In my case I was building the tree structure into a spreadsheet

Comment: In your situation, is this Google Apps Script library useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp

Comment: @salahkai did you try the suggested solution? Please provide feedback on it.

Comment: @Tanaike this seems to work too, a very useful repo thanks you for including it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using recursion:

```js
function myFunction() {


  var getSubfolders = subfoldersObject => {
    var subfolders = []; 
    while(subfoldersObject.hasNext()){
      subfolders.push(subfoldersObject.next())
    } 
    return subfolders;
  }

  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  
   
  function recursive(folder){

    var subFolders = getSubfolders(folder.getFolders());
    return {id: folder.getId(), label: folder.getName(),
             nodes: subFolders.map(folder => recursive(folder))}
  }

  const treeMenu = recursive(rootFolder);
}
```

The trick is to call the same function on every folder you encounter. That will mean calling the function inside itself, which is precisely what we want: to look for folders inside looking for folders inside looking for folders... until we hit a dead end and we come back up one level.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete functional solution

```
function myTreeFoldersV2() {
  const rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  let result = []
  result.push({ name: rootFolder.getName(), id: rootFolder.getId(), pid: 'root', nodes: [] })
  recursive(rootFolder)
  function recursive(parentFolder) {
    var childFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
      var childFolder = childFolders.next();
      result.push({ name: childFolder.getName(), id: childFolder.getId(), pid: parentFolder.getId(), nodes: [] })
      recursive(childFolder);
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2tree(result), null, 2))
}
function arr2tree(ar) {
  var json = [ar[0]]
  recursive(json[0])
  function recursive(obj) {
    obj.nodes.push(ar.filter(a => a.pid == obj.id))
    obj.nodes = obj.nodes.flat()
    for (item in obj.nodes) { recursive(obj.nodes[item]) }
  }
  return json;
}
```

[image]